# Changing list while iterating over it and iterating over new elements

Tags: java, listiterator

i was wondering if this is possible, and if it is, how can i do it?
Basically what i saw, and think is problem is that cursor of iterator is moving when I am using add function(I dont understand iteration perfectly so I dont know if this is problem).The problem happens when i remove one element and then add two more(that is specific case where i found a problem).

My code is something like this:

```
List<String> list =new ArrayList<>();
for (ListIterator<String> iterator = list.listIterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
      //here i am adding and removing elements
```

Comment: Is this Java? It helps if you tell people what language you're using. They differ.

Comment: Anyway, the answer is no you can't, and you don't need to. Iterate over a copy. No clue how you do that in Java, but I'm pretty sure you'll find a dozen examples here on SO.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write that it is java, anyway thanks for reply, but i cant do that because conditions of adding elements depends on elements that i added before.

Comment: You don't need to alter a list when you're iterating through it. If your implementation of your algorithm requires you to do something the language doesn't support, you need to find a more suitable language, or else redesign your code. In this case I'm pretty sure what you need is help with your algorithm. Yeah, you could just use indexes and leave iterators out of it, but you'll spend hours in hell trying to fix a hopelessly broken algorithm. It'll be a valuable learning experience, though. Or you could change the question to ask about how to fix your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

ListIterator According to JLS

> An iterator for lists that allows the programmer to traverse the list
>   in either direction, modify the list during iteration, and obtain the
>   iterator's current position in the list. A ListIterator has no current
>   element; its cursor position always lies between the element that
>   would be returned by a call to previous() and the element that would
>   be returned by a call to next(). An iterator for a list of length n
>   has n+1 possible cursor positions, as illustrated by the carets (^)
>   below:

[image]

You can use the add(), remove() method to make the modification in iterator and same will be reflected in the list reference.

Remove as per JLS

> Removes from the list the last element that was returned by next() or
>   previous() (optional operation). This call can only be made once per
>   call to next or previous. It can be made only if add(E) has not been
>   called after the last call to next or previous.

So if you  use remove twice without calling next() or previous() it will throw  java.lang.IllegalStateException

I modified your code to test add() and remove()

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> list =new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("55");
    list.add("155");
    list.add("255");
    for (ListIterator<String> iterator = list.listIterator(); iterator.hasNext();){

        System.out.println(list.size());
        iterator.add("88");
        System.out.println(list.size());
        iterator.next();
        System.out.println(list.size());
        iterator.remove();
        System.out.println("first remove done");
        iterator.remove();  // will throw exception if previous or next is not called
    }

    System.out.println(list);
}
```